# Google Geocoding API sometimes I can never get results, only get "REQUEST_DENIED"

Tags: php, google-geocoding-api

I have developed a feature related to geocoding API on my site.
My site has many customers, so they access Geocoding API lots of times everyday.(like this url-"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mount+waverley+australia&sensor=false")

Usually, this feature gets excellent result.
But I never change code now, sometimes it gets "REQUEST_DENIED".

I thought this issue was related to limitation of Geocoding API(2500 per day), so I inserted my API key to above url.(like this-"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=mount+waverley+australia&sensor=false&key=XXXXXXXXXXX")

But I got same result-"REQUEST_DENIED".

Why am I getting results like this?
How could I resolve this issue?

Any assistance is welcome, and thank you very much for your reading.

Answer (score 0):

By inserting your key in the URL you will still access the API and thus have the same limits.
If you have a busy site, it's very likely that you have hit the limit.

I would recommend to try and get a fresh API key under another account and see what happens with that one.

If that works correctly, you might have to think about purchasing access (can be expensive) or (if possible in your app) cache the API results locally.